# How do I pass in variables into python import path

Tags: python, import, identifier

I'm trying to find out how I can parameterize a package path but could not figure it out.

Here is an example:

If I do the following, it works, the a, b are a directory names, with `__init__.py` in them, the last directory b contains a c.py file, which contains 'd' as a class name
from a.b.c import d (python takes it without any issue)

I'm trying to make the directory 'b' as a variable that I can pass in dynamically.

Something like: 
b = 'y' <-- This name is figured out somehow dynamically
from a.b.c import d

The above identifier b is a string, python won't take it, looks like I might need: eval(), lambda, getattr() etc to convert the string 'y' into module identifier, but I can't make it working.

Could someone please help me out, thanks a lot in advance!

Bruce

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
wim@wim-imac:/tmp$ find a 
a
a/__init__.py
a/b
a/b/__init__.py
a/b/c
a/b/c/__init__.py
a/y
a/y/__init__.py
a/y/c
a/y/c/__init__.py
wim@wim-imac:/tmp$ cat a/b/c/__init__.py 
d = 'd in b'
wim@wim-imac:/tmp$ cat a/y/c/__init__.py 
d = 'd in y'
```

Now [`importlib`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/importlib.html#importlib.import_module) has what you need:

```
wim@wim-imac:/tmp$ python -i -c ""
>>> from importlib import import_module
>>> mod_a_b_c = import_module('a.b.c')
>>> mod_a_b_c.d
'd in b'
>>> mod_a_y_c = import_module('a.y.c')
>>> mod_a_y_c.d
'd in y'
```

These are convenience wrappers.  If you specifically want to have the "from" style imports, you are going to have to use the [`__import__` magic method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#__import__) directly and use the `fromlist` kwarg.  It's a bit of a drag the syntax, but still possible:

```
>>> d = __import__('a.b.c', fromlist=['d']).d
>>> d
'd in b'
>>> d = __import__('a.y.c', fromlist=['d']).d
>>> d
'd in y'
```

Comment: Wow, thanks a bunch wim, I'm so pleasantly surprised that I got an answer right away, honestly speaking, I didn't have high hope to even get an answer :) Not only a long one, but a thorough one, not only one answer, but two answers, and I just tried the __import__ solution, it worked already with python2.7.5, I can't thank you enough for this. You rock! stackoverflow rock!